# NIC teaming on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, nic, network-teaming

My understanding is that NIC teaming isn't natively supported on Windows 7 OS?!

Is there a way to do it using some third-party tool?

What are your experiences?

Comment: Mainstream support for 7 ended on January 13, 2015, you might want to consider moving on.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 doesn't actually include a feature for NIC teaming—NIC teaming isn't provided by the OS. The implementation of network teaming is delegated to the network card driver, which transparently offers a teamed logical network adapter to the OS. Major network card manufactures such as Intel and Broadcom support NIC teaming in their drivers. Check your NIC firmware whether it provide such options.